# disable the thumbanails displayed in youtube

Tags: jquery, html, youtube

I want to disable the thumbnails in youtube which is listed at the end of the youtube video. I have given the sample video url.at the end thumbnail is listed at the end os the video. I want to disable the thumbnail

[sample url](https://www.youtube.com/embed/jebJ9itYTJE)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use `rel=0` at the end of the embed url.

I'll take your own sample url for example

Change this

https://www.youtube.com/embed/jebJ9itYTJE

To

https://www.youtube.com/embed/jebJ9itYTJE?rel=0